custom comparitor for integers in string vector
I want to sort a vector of strings representing very large (10**6 digits) in ascending order in C++.
I am trying to use a custom comparitor, but the sort is failing when comparing numbers of the same number of digits, eg. failing to re-arrange 82 and 44.
Here is a small example:
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

string ltrim(const string &);
string rtrim(const string &);

bool comp(const string &left, const string &right)
{
    if (left.size() < right.size())
    {
        return true;
    }
    if (left.size() > right.size())
    {
        return false;
    }

    for (unsigned long int i = 0; i < left.size(); i++)
    {
        if (left[i] > (right[i]))
        {
            // left is bigger
            return false;
        }
    }
    // left is smaller or equal
    return true;
}

int main(void)
{
    vector<string> str_nums = {"82", "44", "131", "2"};

    sort(str_nums.begin(), str_nums.end(), comp);

    for (string e : str_nums)
    {
        cout << e << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}

This outputs:
2
82
44
131

where the numbers with different digits are fine, but those with two digits are not sorted.
What is the issue, please?

Use a debugger to see why it decides that 82 < 44.

Using proper projection ensures correctness: return std::tuple{lhs.size(), lhs} < std::tuple(rhs.size(), rhs);

Side notes: (1) Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>? (2) What's the problem with "using namespace std;"?.

Your function doesn't compare numbers, it compares individual characters. It's almost equivalent to left <= right.

In your loop, when left[i] < right[i], you just skip that digit...

If your numbers can have leading 0's, your size comparisons won't be reliable.

What you seem to want is simply std::stoi(left) <= std::stoi(right).

@Someprogrammerdude: < not <= ;-)

What is the issue, please? -- What is a debugger?.  Knowing how to debug your own code is part and parcel of learning how to write programs.  Start to learn to use the debugger on this program that only has the data that you say does not work correctly.

@Someprogrammerdude that's 10^6 digits, not just 10^6; so that's too long for even long long unsigned
stoi also will throw an error since the number is too large

@YWH Then you need to come up with another way to compare numbers. Or use an existing bignum library to help you. Also note that your shown function is ambiguous. For the size it does both less-than and less-or-equal, and for the characters (not numbers) it does less-or-equal. It breaks the strict weak ordering requirement for comparison functions.

Typical compare operators return tri state information <, =, >

First convert the string to a number and then compare them (if your numbers are in the range 1-10^6)! When you compare a string character, it is not the number but ascii numbers are compared. also if you have to compare the ascii numbers you can  do the convert for that one character.

If your assignment or exercise is to implement your own bignum functions, then you might actually want to refresh primary and secondary school math.  Like for example how you did normal arithmetic (addition, division, etc.) using pencil and paper. Much of that can be translated more or less exactly the same in a computer program. For comparison, do a subtraction: Is the result negative? Positive? Zero? That will tell you if the first value is smaller, larger or equal to the second value. So for less-than ordering it's return subtract(left, right) < 0.

Jarod42's and Some programmer dude's comments on strict weak ordering have provided the answer, thank you! The condition where a digit was ignored when it was smaller was the issue

You aren't returning true when you see a larger digit in right, so the later smaller digit is compared and false is returned. N.b. you are not meeting the requirements for std::sort, as returning true when things compare equal is invalid, you need a strict less than.
bool comp(const string &left, const string &right)
{
    if (left.size() < right.size())
    {
        return true;
    }
    if (left.size() > right.size())
    {
        return false;
    }

    for (unsigned long int i = 0; i < left.size(); i++)
    {
        if (left[i] > (right[i]))
        {
            // left is bigger
            return false;
        }
        if (left[i] < right[i])
        {
            // right is bigger
            return true;
        }
    }
    // left is equal
    return false;
}

See it on coliru
However there is a much easier way of doing this comparison, which is to construct a std::tuple of each thing you want to compare, in the order of priority
bool comp(const string &left, const string &right)
{
    return std::forward_as_tuple(left.size(), left) < std::forward_as_tuple(right.size(), right);
}


You need to strip of any leading zeros. Also you don't compare strings, but compare "big numners" so it almost always make sense to write a class that can help you maintain some invariants (like no leading 0's and only digits).
Combine that with C++20's spaceship operator which can compare for smaller/equal/greater you can do it like this:
Live demo: https://onlinegdb.com/zLYAt2MTa
And with the sort order being available you can use std::sort
#include <string>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

class big_number_t
{
public:
    explicit big_number_t(const std::string_view sv)
    {
        if (sv.size() == 0ul) throw std::invalid_argument{ "input must contain at least one digit" };
        requires_all_digits(sv);
        // strip leading zeros

        auto pos = sv.find_first_not_of('0');
        if ( pos == std::string_view::npos )
        {
            m_value = "0";
        }
        else
        {
            m_value = sv.substr(pos);
        }
    }

    // Use C++20 spaceship operator if you can
    // https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_comparisons
    auto operator<=>(const big_number_t& rhs) const
    {
        auto result = m_value.size() <=> rhs.m_value.size();

        if (result == std::strong_ordering::equal)
        {
            for (std::size_t pos{ 0ul }; pos < m_value.size(); ++pos)
            {
                result = m_value[pos] <=> rhs.m_value[pos];
                if (result != std::strong_ordering::equal) break;
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    bool operator==(const big_number_t& rhs) const
    {
        return m_value == rhs.m_value;
    }

    const std::string& str() const noexcept
    {
        return m_value;
    }

private:
    constexpr void requires_all_digits(const std::string_view sv)
    {
        for (const auto c : sv)
        {
            if ((c < '0') || (c > '9'))
            {
                throw std::invalid_argument{ "non digit character found" };
            }
        }
    }

    std::string m_value;
};


int main()
{
    big_number_t zero1{ "0" };
    big_number_t zero2{ "000" };
    assert(zero1 == zero2);

    big_number_t v1{ "12341349801439486140986" };
    big_number_t v2{ "0000056732859713359871" };

    big_number_t v3{ "92801439486140986" };
    big_number_t v4{ "56732859713359871" };

    big_number_t v5{ "92801439486140986" };
    big_number_t v6{ "92801439486140985" };

    big_number_t v7{ "92801439486140985" };
    big_number_t v8{ "92801439486140985" };


    assert(v1 > v2);
    assert(v3 > v4);
    assert(v5 > v6);
    assert(v7 == v8);

    std::vector<big_number_t> numbers{
        big_number_t{ "12341349801439486140986" },
        big_number_t{ "0000056732859713359871" },

        big_number_t{ "92801439486140986" },
        big_number_t{ "56732859713359871" },

        big_number_t{ "92801439486140986" },
        big_number_t{ "92801439486140985" }
    };

    std::sort(numbers.begin(), numbers.end());

    for (const auto& number : numbers)
    {
        std::cout << number.str() << "\n";
    }
}


@Jarod42 Thanks you're right (I was just a bit too quick there)

Code fixed for all zeros input

This is the code:
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm> // std::sort
bool compare_numstrings(std::string &left, std::string &right) {
left = left.substr(left.find_first_not_of('0'));
right = right.substr(right.find_first_not_of('0'));
if (left.size() < right.size()) {
    return true;}
else if (left.size() > right.size()) {
    return false;}
else {
    for (long int i = 0; i < left.size(); i++) {
        if (left[i] < right[i]) {
            return true;}
        else if (left[i] > right[i]) {
            return false;}}
    return true;} // return true when numbers are equal.
};
int main() {
    std::vector<std::string> v_numstrings = {"08221014", "00000013141234", "00013141235", "013141236", "008221014", "01048576", "001048575", "004414201", "04414202"};
    std::sort(v_numstrings.begin(), v_numstrings.end(), compare_numstrings);
    for (std::string numstring: v_numstrings) {
        std::cout << numstring << "\n";}
    return 0;
}


"Without using any strange library"? std::sort is in the same library as std::vector and std::string, i.e. the standard library.

Why would you assume that bubble sort is "more than enough"? And why is your answer mostly focused on replacing the bit that already worked (the std::sort) rather than just the bit that didn't (the predicate)?

The standard library is NOT strange in fact is is HIGHLY recommended to use it when you can.  Writing your own sort method when std::sort can do the job only would require writing and testing more code.

Without using any strange library, this is the way to go -- Honestly, this code would not pass code review for almost every C++ shop -- the programmer working on your code would more than likely just throw it away and get std::sort to work with the proper predicate.  The std::sort always works when given the proper predicate function.

The toxic people arrived in record time, bruh

No we are warning other readers your code is not what experienced developers would write. It is not toxic, it is like teachers trying to teach you something :)  Side note you pass your data by value to your sort function this leads to unecessary copying (which with large strings is an issue)

Guys the code works as intended, i have just added code for removing possible zeros at the beginning. If you want to use sort is fine, I just don't like it. the thing that matters is that the code gets accurate results, and it does

I appreciate the effort you've put into this. However this is not the kind of coding we think other people should copy or use as reference.

It is equivalent of me going to the python section and answering a question by writing a loop instead of using list or set comprehension, and in addition, calling the latter "strange".  The python programmers would say something if I gave a for loop as an answer, just like the C++ programmers are saying something to you for writing your own sort when std::sort exists.  That is not toxic.

Guess what. I'm a noob. For me, sort is strange, I don't know how to use it and I don't need to use it atm. my goal is to make the thing work accurately and it does. I do know some things about python. List comprehension is an alternative to for loops, which has its pros and cons, and using a for loop instead of a list comprehension is not bad as long as the code works as intended, so nobody should even complain about it. Isn't this site about getting things done? He didn't ask for a fancy or pro solution. he only wants a solution, and I'm providing it

The comment section is for comments, and others have commented.  If you post an answer, it is reasonable to accept comments on how the answer can be improved, or why the approach used was taken -- that isn't toxic.   Also, when you post an answer, it is meant not only for the original poster, but for others who may be doing a search and come across the same StackOverflow question.

Bruh I've just learnt how to use sort, so I finally did it using sort
